# Get all health data from react-native-health

Tags: javascript, react-native, healthkit

I am using react-native-health package to get user's health data from Apple health kit,
I can get health data one by one using individual functions, but is there any way to get all health data in a short way?

I am asking for all permissions

```
const permissions = {
  permissions: {
    read: [
        "ActiveEnergyBurned",
        "BasalEnergyBurned",
        "BloodGlucose",
        "BloodPressureSystolic",
        "BloodPressureDiastolic",
        "BodyFatPercentage",
        "BodyMass",
        "BodyMassIndex",
        "BodyTemperature",
        "DietaryEnergyConsumed",
        "DietaryFatTotal",
        "DietaryProtein",
        "DietaryCarbohydrates",
        "DietarySugar",
        "DietaryFiber",
        "DietaryCalcium",
        "DietaryIron",
        "DietaryPotassium",
        "DietarySodium",
        "DietaryVitaminA",
        "DietaryVitaminC",
        "DietaryVitaminD",
        "DietaryVitaminE",
        "DietaryVitaminK",
        "HeartRate",
        "Height",
        "RestingHeartRate",
        "SleepAnalysis",
        "StepCount",
        "Weight",

    ],
    write: [],
  },
}
```

and can get different data using different functions like

```
getEnergyConsumedSamples
getProteinSamples
getFiberSamples
getTotalFatSamples
saveFood
saveWater
getWater
getWaterSamples
getFiberSamples
getInsulinDeliverySamples
saveInsulinDeliverySamples
deleteInsulinDeliverySamples
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no any function available in `react-native-health` to get all health data in a single call. it is also obvious because all the different datatype have different data, so it can not give all the data in a single array of `different format Object`

you can consider my approach to get related data.

```
const METHODS = [
  { id: 1, method: 'getDailyStepCountSamples', name: 'Steps', unit: 'steps' },
  { id: 2, method: 'getSleepSamples', name: 'Sleep', unit: 'sleep' }
]

 const getHealthData1 = async () => {
AppleHealthKit.initHealthKit(permissions, async (error) => {
if (error) {
  console.log('[ERROR] Cannot grant permissions!')
}
const options = {
  startDate: new Date(2022, 1, 1).toISOString(),
  endDate: new Date().toISOString(),
}
let results = []
METHODS.forEach(async (item, index, { length }) => {
  await AppleHealthKit[item?.method](
    options,
    (callbackError, res) => {
      if (res) {
        let itemData = {
          "id": item?.id,
          "name": item?.name,
          "value": (res?.value || res[0]?.value || 0).toFixed(), // store any info you want to save according to your use
          "unit": item?.unit
        }
        results.push(itemData);
      }
      if (length === index + 1) {
        console.log("Results All Data:", JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
      }
    },
  )
})
})
}
```

Happy Coding :)